# VB.NET Accessing Directory

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating a VB.NET Application and require 3 different Projects in my Solution.

The first Project is a Windows Form Application, where users will enter configuration information (API Key and Password, among other things).

The second Project is a Console Application that will be run using a Scheduled Task every 5-10 minutes.

The third (and final) Project is another Console Application that will be run using another Scheduled Task every hours or so, that will access DLLs located in a specific folder and then execute a specific function in each one of those DLLs.

The issue is, both the Windows Form Application and one of the Console Applications need access to a common directory, that being the directory where the DLLs are stored. Those DLLs will be downloaded when the user is using the GUI (Windows Form Application), and on the third Console Application, the DLLs will be loaded and used.

How am I capable of determining the directory where both my Windows Form Application and my Console Application will be able to access common DLLs? Since my Solution has 3 separate Projects, won't any ApplicationPath-type variables direct me to a directory within a specific Project?

Thank you very much

Comment: If this were my project, I would put all of the EXEs and the custom DLLs in the same directory.

Comment: Hi Mike, how would I go about doing that? It was my understanding that in order to have 3 separate EXE files, I needed 3 separate Projects. Is this not the case?

Comment: Yes, three separate projects in Visual Studio to develop and test the applications.

But, just one setup project to create the setup program that will include files from each of the three EXE projects plus the custom DLLs.

Comment: Hm I guess this will require more research on my end, I'm not sure what a Setup Project is..

Comment: There are several tools available to create setup programs. I use InstallShield LE. It is free to purchasers of current versions of Visual Studio. I have used it with both VS2012 and VS2013. InstallShield LE integrates with Visual Studio and lets you create a custom setup.exe using a Setup project in which you define all of the files to be installed on the user's PC and where they come from on your development PC.

Comment: Thanks for all of your input, Mike, I'll look into these tools!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put all of the EXEs and DLLs in the same Program Files directory on your user's PC. To do this, you can use InstallShield LE (free to purchasers of Visual Studio) to create a Setup project in Visual Studio. The Setup project will generate a SETUP.EXE. In the setup project, you declare which files to be installed on the user's PC and where they come from.

There are other tools available to create Setup.exe programs. Others, here, may recommend their favorite.

Comment: Thanks Mike, this will definitely help with any issues I foresaw.